# How to correctly handle API data conversion on frontend with OOP?

Tags: typescript, oop, frontend

I am developing a frontend for a web application using TS. I get stuck on a seemingly simple question: how to transform data object from an API response into a data object for use in the application in a clean way?

Suppose I get a BlogpostAPI object from my API:

```
interface BlogpostAPI {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  createdAt: string;
  // ...and other properties
}
```

And I need to transform it to:

```
interface BlogpostApp {
  title: string;
  content: BlogpostBlock[];
  createdAt: Date;
  // ...and other properties, some of which should be transformed
}

type BlogpostBlock = {
  role: 'body' | 'header';
  text: string;
}
```

I want my code to be clean, i.e. to hide transformation logic into some class. But the solutions I come up with seem somewhat monstrous.

Let's say I want to create a Blogpost class for transformation logic and probably other stuff later on.

```
class Blogpost implements BlogpostApp {
  title: string;
  content: BlogpostBlock[];
  createdAt: Date;

  constructor(post: BlogpostApp) {
    this.title = post.title;
    this.content = post.content;
    this.createdAt = post.createdAt;
  }

  static fromBlogpostAPI(post: BlogpostAPI): Blogpost {
    const content: BlogpostBlock[] = post.content.split('\n').map((s, idx) => {
      if (idx === 0) return { text: s, role: 'header' };
      return { text: s, role: 'body' };
    };
    const createdAt: Date = new Date(post.createdAt);

    return new Blogpost({ title: post.title, content, createdAt });
  }
}
```

This code raises some concerns.

1. The `BlogpostApp` interface is only used to improve readability of the `Blogpost` constructor arguments.
2. If the class has no other purpose but to transform BlogpostAPI interface, then having two identical entities with the same properties (`BlogpostApp` and `Blogpost`) seems messy.

I can also make a class to transform interfaces, but not implementing them:

```
class BlogpostTransformer {
  constructor() {}

  static transform(post: BlogpostAPI): BlogpostApp {
    const content: BlogpostBlock[] = post.content.split('\n').map((s, idx) => {
      if (idx === 0) return { text: s, role: 'header' };
      return { text: s, role: 'body' };
    });
    const createdAt: Date = new Date(post.createdAt);

    return { title: post.title, content, createdAt } as BlogpostApp;
  }
}
```

But now I have a completely separate class with one static method. I will need to make similar classes for any data objects I get from API, and I am not sure if this is a good architecture.

I think there may be some standard way of doing this transformation, but I could not find it. Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@Transform` and `@Type` decorators, and `plainToClass` function of [`class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) package.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Type, Transform, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

interface BlogpostAPI {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  createdAt: string;
}

class BlogpostApp {
  title: string;
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    return value.split('\n').map((s, idx) => {
      if (idx === 0)
        return plainToClass(BlogpostBlock, { text: s, role: 'header' });
      return plainToClass(BlogpostBlock, { text: s, role: 'body' });
    });
  })
  content: BlogpostBlock[];

  @Type(() => Date)
  createdAt: Date;
}

class BlogpostBlock {
  role: 'body' | 'header';
  text: string;
}

const blogpostAPIDTO: BlogpostAPI = {
  title: 'test title',
  content: 'test header\ntest body',
  createdAt: new Date().toString(),
};

const blogpostApp = plainToClass(BlogpostApp, blogpostAPIDTO);

console.log(blogpostApp);
console.log(blogpostApp instanceof BlogpostApp); // true
console.log(blogpostApp.content[0] instanceof BlogpostBlock); // true
console.log(blogpostApp.content[1] instanceof BlogpostBlock); // true
console.log(blogpostApp.createdAt instanceof Date); // true
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jg5dcy?file=index.ts)